# Maven fetching incorrect dependencies

Tags: java, selenium, maven

I have a project where I am updating versions of dependencies. I am getting a very weird behavior where all the selenium related dependencies are hard coded to 3.141.59 version. Although I have updated to selenium 4.3.0. Please see below screenshot:

[image]

What I have tried is

- clear m2 folder and redownload all dependencies
- Delete project and reload it
- Run mvn clean compile -U

But no luck at all.

Comment: Without you POM we cannot say what's wrong.  Perhaps you have a BOM that declares the old versions and you have modified the version of the main dep only.

Comment: @ThomasNaskali, yes thank you. It was the spring boot version that was keeping selenium at 3.x version and never letting it upgrade.